# web data scraping : split html content

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website and I was able to reduce a variable called "gender" to this :

```
[<span style="text-decoration: none;">
                        Lass Christian, du Danemark, à Yverdon-les-Bains, avec 200 parts de CHF 100
                    </span>, <span style="text-decoration: none;">associé gérant </span>]
```

And now I'd like to have **only** "associé" in the variable but I can't find a way to split this html code.

The reason is that I want to know if it's "associé" (male) or "associé**e**" (female).

does anyone have any ideas ?

Cheers

----- edit ---- 
here my code which gets me the html output

```
url = "http://www.rc2.vd.ch/registres/hrcintapp-pub/companyReport.action?rcentId=5947621600000055031025&lang=FR&showHeader=false"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
table = soup.select_one("#adm").find_next("table") #select_one finds only the first tag that matches a selector:
table2 = soup.select_one("#adm").find_all_next("table")


output = table.select("td span[style^=text-decoration:]", limit=2)  #.text.split(",", 1)[0].strip()

print(output)
```

---

Comment: Please show what code produced this output? Thanks.

Comment: yes sure I edit right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the parent of the two elements is you can call `span:nth-of-type(2)` to get the second span, then just check the text:

```
html = """<span style="text-decoration: none;">
                        Lass Christian, du Danemark, à Yverdon-les-Bains, avec 200 parts de CHF 100
                    </span>
           <span style="text-decoration: none;">associé gérant </span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

text = soup.select_one("span:nth-of-type(2)").text
```

Or if it not always the second span you can search for the span by the partial text *associé*:

```
import re
text = soup.find("span", text=re.compile(ur"associé")).text
```

For your edit, all you need is to extract the text last element and use `.split(None, 1)[1]` to get the gender:

```
text = table.select("td span[style^=text-decoration:]", limit=2)[-1].text
gender = text.split(None, 1)[1] # > gérant
```

Comment: it gives me an error : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @J.jaques, . Nothing in my code would do that if you used it correctly. What exactly are you passing?